# PHP == converting "2.5" to 2?

Tags: php, casting, equals, operator-keyword

I'm a bit stumped on this equal operator.

echo (2 == "2.5time")

should output to 1/true.

The "2.5time" string should typecast into an integer and output 2 as an integer.

But it doesn't seem to output anything.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Well, that's the full code as I'm doing a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison is having PHP parse the string and get a number of 2.5 which is a float. it's then comparing it against your integer which gets treated as a float 2.0

Answer (score 4):

If it does not output anything it means that is false, do a var_dump(2 == "2.5time") to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the numbers at the beginning of a string to be handled as an integer, then you have to type cast them as an integer, hence

```
if(2 == (int)"2.5times") // will be true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the == operator, it will be compared all the String.

```
(2 == "2") // is true, because is the same value
(2 === "2") // is false, because is the same value, but is different types
(2 == "23") // is false, contains different values
```

but in your case it will be better use the [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find the substring in a string.